# return datediff as decimal/percent

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, t-sql

i am currently writing a scalar valued function and i'm having a few issue with the returned result.

i have narrowed the problem down to a calulation that convert the difference between two dates as a percentage/decimal. no matter what i try the return value is always a whole number

`set @earnedpremium = (@premium * @pretripearnings) + ((@premium - (@premium * @pretripearnings)) * cast((datediff(day, @outdate, @experiencedate) / datediff(day, @outdate, @returndate))as decimal(5,2)))`

the cast section needs to return the percentage, i know the rest is working fine through some elimination and testing.

can someone please help me figure out what im doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because DATEDIFF returns an INTEGER and so you need to cast both parts of that operation to DECIMAL:

```
set @earnedpremium = (@premium * @pretripearnings) + ((@premium - (@premium * @pretripearnings)) 
* (CAST(datediff(day, @outdate, @experiencedate) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) / 
  CAST(datediff(day, @outdate, @returndate) AS DECIMAL(5,2)))
```